# Lista de meses en español en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Mi pregunta es del framework de `PHP`, [Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel). Cuando pongo

```
{{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}
```

me sale una lista de meses pero en inglés.

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

¿Cómo hago para que me salga en español?

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el contenido de la macro para `Form::selectMonth`?

Answer (score 1):

¿Probaste configurar en español `fallback_locales = 'es'`? En `config/app.php` ([Localization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization))

Answer (score 1):

`selectMonth()` usa `strftime()`, entonces solo necesitas cambiar esto como se dice en el [manual de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php)